# Pass array through apply function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Is it possible to pass individual elements of an array through the apply function in a pandas dataframe?  In the below example, I would like to pass the number "2" in the array for the first row in the dataframe, then 3 for the second row, etc.  In this example, the values in column C would be `[3, 5, 7, 9]`. Thank you for your help.

```
df = {"A" : [1,2,3,4], "B" : [10, 20, 30, 40]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def addArray(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

array = [2,3,4,5]

df.apply(addArray, axis=1, args = (array))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `apply` function

```
import pandas as pd

df = {"A" : [1,2,3,4], "B" : [10, 20, 30, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def addArray(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

df['C'] = pd.Series([2,3,4,5])
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: addArray(row['A'], row['C']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without first including the array into the original dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to pass individual elements of an array through the `apply` function in a Pandas DataFrame.
here is an example

```
import pandas as pd

df = {"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [10, 20, 30, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def addArray(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

array = [2, 3, 4, 5]

df['C'] = array

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: addArray(row['A'], row['C']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C
0  1  10  3
1  2  20  5
2  3  30  7
3  4  40  9
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without first including the array into the original dataframe?